# hhline thickness and line extension

Tags: tables, hhline

AS shown in the MWE below, I am using hhline instead of cmidrule to draw horizontal lines along specific cells in a table. I have 2 queries:

- First, how can I remove the white extension of the hhline which appears along the whole row. I need a way to avoid the conflict between colored rows and `hhline`;
- Is there an argument in such command to control line thickness as in     `cmidrule {1.25pt}{3-7}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{hhline} 



\newcolumntype{C}{>{\babelsublr\bgroup}c<{\egroup}} 




\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 
\rowcolor{gray!25}
&   &   &  
\\ 
\hhline{~--~}
\rowcolor{gray!25}
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 
\rowcolor{gray!25}
&   &   &  
\\ 
\hhline{~~~~}
\rowcolor{gray!25}
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
&
\multirow{-2}{*}{m}
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the   white strips, you may use this; `\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!25}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!25}}-}`. A to the \hhline width, you can set it as `\arrayrulewidth`, but this width will be fixed for the whole environment.

Comment: Regarding the arrayrule width, will it be fixed for the whole document even if I defined it inside the hhline?

Comment: @Bernard, also such command interferes with the general settings of the colors of the lines, thus the lines afterwards take the last color setting. Is there a way to make it local to the command?

Comment: @Bernard, even upon using the solution shown above, the issue still presists

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the last command inside `\hhline`: complete `>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!25}}-` this way:  `>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!25}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}|`.